# EJB 3.1 Dependency Injection Failed

Tags: java, dependencies, ejb, code-injection

i have created a stateless session bean like this :

```
@WebServlet(name = "ProductController", urlPatterns = {"/ProductController"})
public class ProductController extends HttpServlet {

  @EJB
  private ProductFacadeBean productBean;
}

@Stateless
public class ProductFacadeBean extends AbstractFacade<Product> implements ProductFacadeLocalInterface {
  @PersistenceContext(unitName = "OnlineStorePU")
  private EntityManager em;

  protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
    return em;
  }

  public ProductFacadeBean() {
    super(Product.class);
  }

}

@Local
public interface ProductFacadeLocalInterface {

  void create(Product product);

  void edit(Product product);

  void remove(Product product);

  Product find(Object id);

  List<Product> findAll();

  List<Product> findRange(int[] range);

  int count();

}


public abstract class AbstractFacade<T> {
  private Class<T> entityClass;

  public AbstractFacade(Class<T> entityClass) {
    this.entityClass = entityClass;
  }

  protected abstract EntityManager getEntityManager();

  public void create(T entity) {
    getEntityManager().persist(entity);
  }

  public void edit(T entity) {
    getEntityManager().merge(entity);
  }

  public void remove(T entity) {
    getEntityManager().remove(getEntityManager().merge(entity));
  }

  public T find(Object id) {
    return getEntityManager().find(entityClass, id);
  }

  public List<T> findAll() {
    javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery cq = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
    cq.select(cq.from(entityClass));
    return getEntityManager().createQuery(cq).getResultList();
  }

  public List<T> findRange(int[] range) {
    javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery cq = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
    cq.select(cq.from(entityClass));
    javax.persistence.Query q = getEntityManager().createQuery(cq);
    q.setMaxResults(range[1] - range[0]);
    q.setFirstResult(range[0]);
    return q.getResultList();
  }

  public int count() {
    javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery cq = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
    javax.persistence.criteria.Root<T> rt = cq.from(entityClass);
    cq.select(getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().count(rt));
    javax.persistence.Query q = getEntityManager().createQuery(cq);
    return ((Long) q.getSingleResult()).intValue();
  }

}
```

Question :

1. What is the error about ? How to
   solve it ?

   > javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup
   >   failed for
   >   'java:comp/env/Controller.ProductController/productBean'
   >   in
   >   SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory,
   >   java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl,
   >   java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming}
   >   [Root exception is
   >   javax.naming.NamingException:
   >   Exception resolving Ejb for 'Remote
   >   ejb-ref
   >   name=Controller.ProductController/productBean,Remote
   >   3.x interface =EJB.ProductFacadeBean,ejb-link=null,lookup=,mappedName=,jndi-name=EJB.ProductFacadeBean,refType=Session'
   >   .  Actual (possibly internal) Remote
   >   JNDI name used for lookup is
   >   'EJB.ProductFacadeBean#EJB.ProductFacadeBean'
   >   [Root exception is
   >   javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup
   >   failed for
   >   'EJB.ProductFacadeBean#EJB.ProductFacadeBean'
   >   in
   >   SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory,
   >   java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl,
   >   java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming}
   >   [Root exception is
   >   javax.naming.NameNotFoundException:
   >   EJB.ProductFacadeBean#EJB.ProductFacadeBean
   >   not found]]]

The full exception is attached here :

```
HTTP Status 500 -

type Exception report

message

descriptionThe server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: PWC1392: Error instantiating servlet class Controller.ProductController

root cause

com.sun.enterprise.container.common.spi.util.InjectionException: Error creating managed object for class Controller.ProductController

root cause

com.sun.enterprise.container.common.spi.util.InjectionException: Exception attempting to inject Remote ejb-ref name=Controller.ProductController/productBean,Remote
3.x interface =EJB.ProductFacadeBean,ejb-link=null,lookup=,mappedName=,jndi-name=EJB.ProductFacadeBean,refType=Session into class Controller.ProductController

root cause

javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'java:comp/env/Controller.ProductController/productBean' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Exception resolving Ejb for 'Remote ejb-ref name=Controller.ProductController/productBean,Remote
3.x interface =EJB.ProductFacadeBean,ejb-link=null,lookup=,mappedName=,jndi-name=EJB.ProductFacadeBean,refType=Session' .  Actual (possibly internal) Remote JNDI name used for lookup is 'EJB.ProductFacadeBean#EJB.ProductFacadeBean' [Root exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'EJB.ProductFacadeBean#EJB.ProductFacadeBean' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: EJB.ProductFacadeBean#EJB.ProductFacadeBean not found]]]

root cause

javax.naming.NamingException: Exception resolving Ejb for 'Remote ejb-ref name=Controller.ProductController/productBean,Remote
3.x interface =EJB.ProductFacadeBean,ejb-link=null,lookup=,mappedName=,jndi-name=EJB.ProductFacadeBean,refType=Session' .  Actual (possibly internal) Remote JNDI name used for lookup is 'EJB.ProductFacadeBean#EJB.ProductFacadeBean' [Root exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'EJB.ProductFacadeBean#EJB.ProductFacadeBean' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: EJB.ProductFacadeBean#EJB.ProductFacadeBean not found]]

root cause

javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'EJB.ProductFacadeBean#EJB.ProductFacadeBean' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: EJB.ProductFacadeBean#EJB.ProductFacadeBean not found]

root cause

javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: EJB.ProductFacadeBean#EJB.ProductFacadeBean not found

note The full stack traces of the exception and its root causes are available in the GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1 logs. GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1
```

1. When i created the session for
   entity bean using netbeans it
   created the abstract facade for us ?
   What is the purpose ? I know facade
   pattern is to serve as interface to
   route the request ?
2. What is the use of ejb-jar.xml ?

All settings are default. 
The ejb bean is created inside java ee 6 web application rather than in another war or jar. 
Glassfish 3.1 server.

Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: I hope someone can help on this topic.

Comment: Problem solved by inject interface rather than concrete class.

Comment: Why changing from ProductBean to @EJB 
  private ProductFacadeLocalInterface productBean and it works ?

Comment: If the interface is implemented by two concrete class, how container will know which to instantiate ?

Comment: Did you get any answer to your last question ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you must use the interface. If you use `Seam Solder` and `CDI` you can specify the exact implementation with

```
@Inject
@Exact(ProductFacadeBean.class)
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to inject the bean by refering to its interface and not to its implementation directly.  Something like this ..

```
@EJB
private ProductFacadeLocalInterface productBean;
```

You can then access the bean using the interface methods that you exposed in `ProductFacadeLocalInterface`.

Comment: Why not inject the implementation directly rather than its interface ? If have two classes, then i need we need to marked one class with premium.

Comment: When an EJB, in your case a stateless bean, implements any local/remote interface, it needs to be accessed using the interface.  In JavaEE6 and EJB3.1 it is possible to have interface-less beans and inject directly the implementation but should be avoided for design and maintainability reasons.

Comment: @aseychell What about peterwkc's question ? If you have 2 EJB which implement an interface, how does the container know which one to pick ?

Comment: @Unda You cant't. You have to create a Local interface for each Stateless bean which extends the common interface.