# EJB3 Injection failed on JBoss AS 5.1 Error: ClassLoaders of value and target are not equal

Tags: java, jboss, ejb

I'm trying to inject a SLSB into a servlet but got the following error:

`ERROR [org.jboss.injection.lang.reflect.FieldBeanProperty] (HDScanner) failed to set value Proxy to jboss.j2ee:ear=contact.ear,jar=contact-ejb.jar,name=ContactServiceBean,service=EJB3 implementing [interface com.test.contactservice.ContactService] on field private com.test.contactservice.ContactServiceBean com.test.contactmanager.controller.ContactController.cBean; Reason: ClassLoaders of value and target are not equal`

Here is the annotation on the EJB:

```
@Stateless(name="ContactServiceBean")
@Local
public class ContactServiceBean implements ContactService {
```

The servlet has the following annotation:

```
@EJB(mappedName="contact/ContactServiceBean/local")
private ContactServiceBean cBean;
```

My web.xml uses 2.5 schema:

```
<web-app version="2.5"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
```

Could someone please take a look?  Any suggestion would be much appreciated.

---

@AntonioP:  I thought packaging the EJB into the war only works in EJB3.1.  I believe it's not supported in JBoss 5.1.

I've tried renaming the mappedName as you suggested but got NameNotFoundException.  I forgot to mention in my original post that the EJB is bounded to the following entry in Global JNDI:

[org.jboss.ejb3.proxy.impl.jndiregistrar.JndiSessionRegistrarBase] (HDScanner) Binding the following Entries in Global JNDI:

```
    contact/ContactServiceBean/local - EJB3.x Default Local Business Interface
    contact/ContactServiceBean/local-com.test.contactservice.ContactService - EJB3.x Local Business Interface
```

My EAR has the following directory structure:

```
contact.ear
 |
 ___META-INF
      |
      ___application.xml
 |
 ___contact.war
 |
 ___contact-ejb.jar
```

Thanks.

Comment: FYI - I linked this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6183670/ejb-3-1-dependency-injection-failed) with yours so that others stumbling on this can see the other post that helped you solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Are the servlet and SSLB in the same jar or war? They need to be. Also check

```
@EJB(mappedName="contact/ContactServiceBean/local")
```

Try with

```
@EJB(mappedName="com/test/contact/ContactServiceBean/local")
```

or just ContactServiceBean/local

Check this post http://community.jboss.org/message/8196#8196